# Maxwell Equations in Earth frame

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, reference-frames, speed-of-light, aether

Considering that the luminiferous ether exists around earth, if all electrodynamics experiments are done in earth frame how do we know that the speed of light $c$ we calculated from it is not $c$ with respect to the earth?

This Statement is from Griffith's book of Electrodynamics

> If Maxwell’s equations are valid only with respect to the ether frame, any discrepancy between the experimental result and the theoretical prediction would be ascribable to the ether wind."
> Maxwell Equation itself is derived in earth frame.

After all, $c$ comes from permeability and permittivity of space (experiment calculated).

Answer (score 5):

> if all electrodynamics experiments are done in earth frame how do we know that the speed of light  we calculated from it is not  with respect to the earth?

First, not all electrodynamics experiments are done at rest with respect to the earth frame, nor necessarily close to the earth. However, for the sake of discussion let’s limit ourselves to experiments carried out near the earth surface.

Around 1900 most theories of electrodynamics under consideration were aether theories, that posited a material medium in which electromagnetism propagated. The fact that light could be transverse polarized indicated that it was probably a solid, and the high speed of light indicated that it was probably very rigid and not very dense.

If there were a rigid aether then at some point in the day/year earth would move with respect to it. Standard interferometers could test that hypothesis. Those experiments were performed and ruled out rigid aether theories.

The next idea was a dragged aether, perhaps it was a strange fluid medium that was pulled along at the earth’s surface. This would explain the result of the standard interferometer experiments, and is essentially what you are describing in the question. This hypothesis could be tested using a ring interferometer. Those experiments were performed and ruled out dragged aether theories. Basically, if the speed of light were c relative to the earth, a ring interferometer would not detect any rotation. Since they do detect a rotation of one revolution per sidereal day, those theories are falsified.

So with rigid aether theories ruled out by standard interferometers and with dragged aether theories ruled out by ring interferometer experiments, the only aether theory which is unfalsified is the Lorentz aether theory, which is experimentally indistinguishable from no aether.